# AngularJS SPA and windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I wanna authenticate my AngularJS Site users with on premise Microsoft active directory. Is there any AngularJs plug-ins or way available to do this?

SO can we use windows authentication from front-end only, without involvement of server side code?